# How to use a Spark UDF that takes an array of struct as an argument in order to build a new column?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have the following `df` DataFrame:

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contractId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contractArray: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- profile: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
+---------------+----------------------------------------+
|code|contractId|                           contractArray|
+---------------+----------------------------------------+
|   A|      45 8|    [{CONSUMER, 789}, {SUBSCRIBER, 789}]|
|  AC|    7896 0|                      [{CONSUMER, null}]|
|  BB|      12 7|  [{CONSUMER, null}, {SUBSCRIBER, null}]|
| CCC|     753 8|  [{SUBSCRIBER, null}, {CONSUMER, 7854}]|
+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

The goal is to create a column named `subscriberPresent` which would contain a boolean based on the content of the `id` and `profile` columns. The condition to respect for the contents of the `subscriberPresent` column is:

```
if(col("role") === "SUBSCRIBER" && col("id") != null) true 
else false
```

So, the desired result is the following:

```
+---------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
|code|contractId|                           contractArray|subscriberPresent|
+---------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+
|   A|      45 8|    [{CONSUMER, 789}, {SUBSCRIBER, 789}]|             true|
|  AC|    7896 0|                      [{CONSUMER, null}]|            false|
|  BB|      12 7|  [{CONSUMER, null}, {SUBSCRIBER, null}]|            false|
| CCC|     753 8|  [{SUBSCRIBER, null}, {CONSUMER, 7854}]|            false|
+-----------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

I was thinking of making a UDF to handle this case but there may be another way to achieve it. Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result without using a **UDF** by using built-in
`when` and `exists` functions in Spark.

Try out this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, expr}

// Create a SparkSession (if you haven't already)
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

// Assuming your DataFrame is already defined as 'df'
val resultDF = df.withColumn(
  "subscriberPresent",
  expr("exists(contractArray, x -> x.profile = 'SUBSCRIBER' and x.id is not null)")
)

resultDF.show()
```